# 'How to stream a large json doc through the node.js mongodb driver efficiently?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, stream

I am writing a node.js app that makes a query to a mongodb database through the mongo node.js driver. I want to route to a link where a large json document is rendered, however, I would like to stream the document for performance considerations.

The code is the following:

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/database",   function(err,db) {
  var query = db.collection("manzanas").find({ "_id": "query" })
                .project({ "_id":0 });

  app.get("/link", function(req,res) {
      query.stream().on("data", function(d) { res.json(d); });
      query.stream().on("end", function() { console.log("done"); res.end(); });
  });

});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("server is on!");
});
```

The problem is that the first time I try to visit the link everything works as expected, but when I try to refresh the page or access the route from either another tab or browser the json document is not rendered while the page is trying to refresh as though the internet connection was very slow; and eventually nothing is displayed.

I have no clue on how to fix it, if I don't stream the document and just display it as it is I encounter no problems, however, I would like to know how to make it work with a stream. In order to make it work again I have to exit the node.js process completely but that is not an option for a production mode scenario.

How can I achieve this and what is the best approach? Is there a better way to do this without using express.js? Any comments are well appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead

```
  app.get("/link", function(req,res) {
      var query = db.collection("manzanas").find({ "_id": "query" })
                .project({ "_id":0 });
      query.stream().on("data", function(d) { res.json(d); });
      query.stream().on("end", function() { console.log("done"); res.end(); });
  });
```

I.e. generate the query each time you request and stream on it.